# How could a secret, global organization control governments and manipulate world events?

Tags: internal-consistency, government, secret-society

So I'm working on a series that is kicked off by a secret organization kidnapping the super human protagonists. This organization is supposed to be worldwide, with its hooks in all major governments and businesses, and is controlled by a group of super humans. Their current goal in the story is to collect a genetically diverse group of humans and super humans because they plan on restarting humanity to prevent an even worse disaster. They are not straight villains, as their goal is to protect humanity, but they are willing to do anything in pursuit of that goal.

The main question I have is fairly simple. How can this organization reliably control established governments without revealing itself?

Obviously this group has access to technology and resources beyond what we have today, but how would they use it to accomplish their goals?

Comment: Do the members of the secret organization live for a very long time?

Comment: Yes, especially the higher ups. In my story super humans have longer life spans and the members of this organization have had genetic tinkering on top of that.

Comment: Sounds like you're rewriting ''The X files''.

Comment: Huh, I never thought about that. I don't think that the story itself is that similar, but the whole secret organization thing isn't exactly a "new" idea is it?

Comment: You're basically asking us to write your script ! Why don't you take a good book on the illuminati.

Comment: Not only X-Files, this is touching on Assassin's Creed as well.

Comment: If anyone answers correctly we'll have to make them disappear. :-)

Comment: See http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneWorldOrder and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheIlluminati for scads of references for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

So this sounds like an Illuminati society, and I think there are a bunch of ways the could influence companies and people.

**Investors**

Some members could be extremely wealthy and influential investors. If they invest in a technology, it would have enough money to thrive and if they don't then other investors are dissuaded and won't attempt to invest as much. With their investment, they would gain some influence over the company, and if there are multiple families they could multiple the amount of influence they could assert. As the rich and powerful, they would have many connections and be able to influence a large number of other rich people, especially if the other people built a fortune along side them.

**Top Scientists and Engineers**

Some members would be incredibly smart and integrate into society as scientists, engineers, soldiers and so on. While they keep their identity a secret, they would be close to the top of their field. Their opinions would be widely valued and with their secret society information, they would be able to shape industries and growth and advancement. They could also act as teachers and mentors and direct people along certain research paths or promote certain methods to approach problems and think about solutions to better influence the path and decisions they make.

**Corporations**

Some of these illuminati would run giant mega corporations as well as small ones.  They could own many other companies (like the murdochs? but spread over many industries and with multiple corporations). They would be able to dictate what the companies under them do, show and how to behave.

**Family and Friends**

Some members would be introduced to influential people at an early age and oversee them their entire lives. Like an Uncle, or Grandparent type figure. They would be introduced to chosen or influential families and continue to support them over their life time. That way, then the family or person comes into power, they may value the opinions of this family friend.

**Issues**

There are definitely some problems with these approaches. If you plan it out properly, all of the influences can't all have the same opinion at the same time. They would have to argue among themselves otherwise people get suspicious. They also can't directly influence people, but can provide suggestions, thoughts and go along certain directions. The top 3 options are all in the spotlight and their influence is more direct so there is more scrutiny on them. You can also mix and match options how you like. I'm sure there are more ways for this to work.

Comment: I hadn't really thought about the family and friends aspect of it, but I like it. It's exactly the type of indirect type of manipulation I was after and somehow I missed it in brainstorming.

Comment: It would be a very interesting concept. I'd imagine it would be incredibly hard, like an inception like thing to get people to act the way they want to.

Comment: I agree, which is one reason why I've been struggling with the suspension of disbelief on this. I don't want to take the easy way out (aka mind control) because I want it to be a little more subtle.

Answer (score 2):

If it's run by superhumans quite easily. However, people are readily seduced into joining elite organizations especially organizations and institutions that have an inside running on controlling and improving the world.

There are already a plethora of similar organizations in the world as we know it. Religions, charities, the armed forces, political parties, and, of course, the cults. Plus there are organizations specialize in enhancing networking and the promotion of their own members like the Lions and Freemasons. There is no need to mention scouts because is too far on the Dark Side.

Cults, of course, are the perfect vehicle for recruiting vast armies of acolytes, enablers and minions. The main disadvantage of cult organizations as potential secret masters of the universe is they are run by people who can only be described as "fruit cakes". This term means they are not suitable for controlling governments or manipulating word events. However, if a cult was run by a cadre of superhuman beings who had all their marbles intact their organization should have little difficulty in running the world from the shadows.

In fact, such organization would function better if instead of operating through one single organization it had a slew of different organizations as its tentacles. It have a number of cults, set up and run political parties around the world, institute charities and non-government organizations, foster religions, and have many of its member infiltrate public services, the armed forces, and other government institutions and entities. Its members could stand for election or even be responsible for the machine politics inside political parties.

Funding, of course, should be easy enough. That's what they would have the cults, charities, and religious groups for.

All things considered it should be easy enough for them to be on the winning side and be the *real* rulers of the world. Mmm. Wonder how easy it would be to join them?

Comment: The whole multiple sub-organizations thing is awesome, and actually a plot point in the story! This answer also gives me hope because the "All things it should be easy enough for them to be on the winning side and be the real rulers of the world" comment is exactly how I want to portray them.